# Complete the pattern of a cube

Tags: geometry

[image][image: pattern of a cube]

We consider the following pattern for a cube. There is one face missing. What are the possibilities ?

I have added the first picture to summarize my question. The numbers give the location of the 6th face.

---

My attempt :

All the faces have already their opposite face, except the face on the east of $13$ ( so on the west of $9$). We note this face $F$

The opposite face of $F$ could be :

- $4$ : deplacement $NN$
- $2$ : deplacement $NWWN$

Why ? How to search the possibilities ?

Comment: What would answering one of the touching-corner squares 1,6,8,10,12,15 even mean?

Comment: How does the diagram give a "pattern for a cube"?

Comment: In elementary school, you want to create a cube, so you fold 6 squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would go around the boundary of the yellow shaded region and mark matching pairs of edges.  The remaining edges that are not matched would then be candidates for the sixth face.

[image]

As you can see, only the topmost edge of the boundary of the figure cannot be matched up.  Placing any square on the numbered spaces adjacent to this edge will permit a cube to be folded from the resulting net.

Answer (score 2):

Let's play a game:  "You can't do that!"

The unfolded cube can't have five faces in a row because the folded cube does not have any rings of five faces -- eliminate 7 and 16.

The unfolded cube can't have two faces sharing only a corner unless another face shares an edge with them -- eliminate 1,6,8,10,12,15.

The cube cannot have four faces touching one vertex -- eliminate 9 and 13.

The cube can't have more than four faces touching any one edge or an endpoint thereof -- eliminate 14 (the bottom edge of 13 would violate this rule) and 11 (the top and right edges of 13 are one edge of the cube).

We are left with 2,3,4,5 -- each of which can be experimentally verified to produce a cube.

Comment: With $1$ or $6$ perhaps you could fold to get a cube while retaining the touching corner

Comment: Possibly.  But usually an unfolded cube has all faces sharing at least one edge, and I assume that is what is meant.  If not, I consider it an ambiguity.