# Fold a cube : pattern

Tags: geometry

[image: fold a cube]
[image: explanation]

We want to fold a cube. Following [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123722/complete-the-pattern-of-a-cube), the unmatched vertices are adjacent to $O,PG,K$.

So the solutions are $O,P,G,K$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: It is correct but does not fit the other two diagrams which could be extended to create other options to unfold a cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $11$ *nets* of the cube:

[image: 11nets]

Image from [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Net.html) article on Nets.